# How to debug if conditions in a C homework assignment?

Tags: python-2.7

Here are my homework requirements:

- RaoMartian, who has at least 3 antenna and at most 4 eyes;
- BrownVenerian, who has at most 6 antenna and at least 2 eyes;
- YeungMoon, who has at most 2 antenna and at most 3 eyes.

My current code:

```
eyes=input("How many eyes? ")
antennas= input("How many antennas? ")

if (antennas<=0) or (eyes<=0):
    print ""
elif(antennas>=3) and (eyes<=4):
    print "RaoMartian"
elif (antennas<=6) and (eyes>=2):
    print "BrownVenerian"
elif (antennas<=2) and (eyes<=3):
    print "YeungMoon"
```

This is what the input should look like:

```
How many eyes? 1
How many antennas? 4
RaoMartian

How many eyes? 3
How many antennas? 2
BrownVenerian
YeungMoon

How many eyes? 6
How many antennas? 8
""
```

When I enter 3 for eyes and 2 for antennas, I only get "BrownVenerian", but I expect to also get "YeungMoon".

Comment: Why is this being down-voted and marked for close? It has sample code plus desired output.

Comment: The general way to solve this problem is to take a pencil and step through each line manually with the values that don't work.

Comment: YeungMoon are a subset of BrownVenerian - perhaps you could do nested ifs - once you find a possible BrownVenerian, an inner if will check for the other.... or check YeungMoon first.

Comment: Get rid of the elifs and just use ifs, as there's overlap in the categories (they're not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @tdelaney: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because of the absolutely useless title, which does nothing but beg for homework help. It does not describe a problem or ask a meaningful question of any sort, and will be of not use to a future reader when they see it in a search result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `elif` statements causes your code to only take a single path through the alternatives. You need to use separate `if` statements to test the different conditions individually:

```
if (antennas>=3) and (eyes<=4):
    print "RaoMartian"
if (antennas<=6) and (eyes>=2):
    print "BrownVenerian"
if (antennas<=2) and (eyes<=3):
    print "YeungMoon"
```

Answer (score 1):

"elif" is a shortcut for "else if".
That means that the code inside that block will be executed only if the previous if statement resulted in a false condition. You are seeing that print in the console because one of the conditions was true, hence not evaluating the following elif's. If you want to allow multiple conditions, change the elifs for normal ifs.